# How can I play Worms Armageddon on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, worms-armageddon

I am experiencing trouble with *Worms Armageddon* on Windows 7; the program crashes after launch.  The game runs perfectly under Windows XP.  Launching the game in compatibility mode does not help.  How can I play the game?

Comment: Does it crash on the introduction screen?

Comment: Could you provide more information on the specific issue you are seeing when you try to run the game? Any messages? Anything in the event log? Also, where did you get your copy of the game? Is it a physical disc? Something else?

Comment: It shows black screen as if the game is going to launch, then after some blinking an error message appears saying "The program has stopped working".

Comment: Have you tried updating the game with the latest patch?

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you are running the latest version (currently v3.7.2.1).

Notice how they mention Windows 2000 support on the updates page linked below. As WA is a game released in 1999 where the NT family wasn't popular yet, it is bound to have many issues on those OS'es unpatched.

Also, kudos to Team17 for releasing patches 13 years after initial release.

http://wormsarmageddon.team17.com/main.html?page=supp&area=upda

Comment: This worked for me after setting WA.exe to `Run as Administrator` and `Run in compatibility mode for Windows XP, SP3`

Answer (score 5):

H​i​,​ [Worms Armageddon maintainer](http://worms2d.info/User:CyberShadow) here. First, you'll want to make sure you have the latest update version for the game:

- If you are using the Steam edition, make sure that automatic updates are enabled. You could also *Verify Integrity of game cache* from the game's Steam properties, however note that this will unfortunately reset your teams.
- If you are using the CD edition, you can download the latest update from Team17's website, [here](http://wa.team17.com/main.html?page=supp&area=upda&file=15).

There is not much information to go by just from your problem description, but another thing you could try is making W:A use a different graphics API. You can do this by browsing to the directory where W:A is installed, opening the **Tweaks** subdirectory, then in turn importing one of **Renderer_Direct3D_7.reg**, **Renderer_Direct3D_9_Shader_Palette.reg**, and **Renderer_DirectDraw_32bit.reg**, then attempting to start the game. Try the next .reg file if one doesn't work.

You can find a comprehensive troubleshooting FAQ for Worms Armageddon on the Worms Knowledge Base Wiki: http://worms2d.info/Troubleshooting_FAQ

If nothing else works, you can contact us directly by email: devs-at-worms2d-dot-info.

Answer (score 2):

Going on the assumption the game crashes at launch and therefore the inroduction screen, disabling the introduction screen might solve your problem, to do this:

right-click the WA shortcut icon, select properties, and in the "Target" text box, type "/nointro" at the end of the path.

This must be outside of the quotation marks for it to work. For example:

> "C:\Worms Armageddon\wa.exe" /nointro

Comment: Tried, still "WA.exe has stopped working"...

Answer (score 2):

Easy solution.

1. Download VMware
2. Open VMware and install Windows XP on it
3. Put your Worms Armageddon CD in and install
4. Play and enjoy :)

Comment: That assumes that he has the spare processing power / RAM to fully run VMWare in a state that won't be laggy in running a game...even an older one such as this.

Comment: It also assumes you have a spare Windows XP product key. It makes the solution a bit expensive.

Comment: You can enable Direct3D acceleration in the VMWare guest, if both host and guest will be Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues. These are the things I needed to do to get it running:

- In the Worms folder, find `WA.exe` and `Right-Click->Properties`
- Set `Run as Administrator`
- Set `Run in compatibility mode for Windows XP, SP3`
- Apply and OK
- In the same folder as `WA.exe`, `Right-Click->New->Text Document`
- Paste in the following:

> @echo off
> TASKKILL /IM explorer.exe /F
> start /B /I /WAIT WA.exe
> start explorer.exe

- Save as `Worms.bat` (Make sure the file type is set to `All files`, not `Text Document`)
- Create a shortcut to this `bat` file on your desktop or something.

If you don't like the command prompt window showing up, you can run the `bat` file from within a powershell script. See my edit to PaN1C_Showt1Me's answer on [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8210/how-do-i-run-starcraft-brood-war-on-windows-7-without-problems) question. To summarise:

- Create another file (with a `.vbs` extension) and paste:

> Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
> WshShell.Run chr(34) & "Worms.bat" & Chr(34), 0
> Set WshShell = Nothing

- Run this file instead of the `bat` file